# Fetching the value for the latest date in the column index

Tags: python

my table looks something like this:

| Sector | 4/1/2022 | 5/1/2022 | 6/1/2022 | 1Y Min |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 10 | 05 | 12 | 05 |
| B | 18 | 20 | 09 | 09 |
| C | 02 | 09 | 12 | 02 |

I want to add a new column "Bps away from 1Y Min" such that values of the new column is calculated using the formula: (Value as of the latest date - 1Y Min)
I want to keep the latest date column dynamic within the formula such that it gets updated whenever a column with a new date is available.

For eg:-

| Sector | 4/1/2022 | 5/1/2022 | 6/1/2022 | 1Y Min | Bps away from 1Y Min |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 10 | 05 | 12 | 05 | 7 |
| B | 18 | 20 | 09 | 09 | 0 |
| C | 02 | 09 | 12 | 02 | 10 |

I tried using the following however it is picking the earliest date instead of the latest date:

```
def dt_helper(dt_string):
    try:
        return datetime.datetime.strptime(dt_string, '%m/%d/%Y').date()
    except:
        return datetime.date(1900,1,1)

df['Bps away from 1Y Min'] = df[max(df.columns, key=dt_helper)] - df('1Y Min')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this way

what's happening here

- save df column names to list
- remove str type list elemnts(assuming str column names don't change)
- Sort list based on dates

*Subract max date - 1Y Min column

```
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd

l=df.columns.tolist()

l.remove('Sector')
l.remove('1Y Min')

from datetime import datetime

y = max(l)
df['Bps away from 1Y Min']= df[y]-df['1Y Min']
print(df)
```

output

```
Sector  4/1/2022  5/1/2022  6/1/2022  1Y Min     Bps away from 1Y Min
0      A        10         5        12       5                     7
1      B        20        20         9       9                     0
2     C         30        20        12       2                    10
>>>
```

Comment: Getting the error: module 'datetime' has no attribute 'strptime'

Comment: change this line to `y=max(l, key=lambda d: datetime.datetime.strptime(d, '%m/%d/%Y'))`

Comment: Tried that as well previously, error: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not datetime.date

Comment: can you print `l` after `l.remove('1Y Min')` ...like `print(l)` & can you paste list here?

Comment: [datetime.date(2021, 4, 30),
 datetime.date(2021, 5, 28),
 datetime.date(2021, 6, 25),
 datetime.date(2021, 7, 30),
 datetime.date(2021, 8, 27),
 datetime.date(2021, 9, 24),
 datetime.date(2021, 10, 29),
 datetime.date(2021, 11, 26),
 datetime.date(2021, 12, 31),
 datetime.date(2022, 1, 28),
 datetime.date(2022, 2, 25),
 datetime.date(2022, 3, 25),
 datetime.date(2022, 4, 29),
 datetime.date(2022, 5, 27),
 datetime.date(2022, 6, 24),
 datetime.date(2022, 7, 29),
 datetime.date(2022, 8, 12)]

Comment: Edited the code..Try know & let me know.

Comment: what do you mean by earliest date and latest date? As I can check max will always pick the maximum date i.e., whichever date column is most recent.

Comment: Yes aim is to select `Latest date` which also indirectly means need to get `Max` date from the list of dates. Max date will be latest date. Isn't that right? Am i missing anything?